# Add new column to a list of data frames

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code

```
df = [ ]

for filename in sorted(glob.glob(dirname + '/*.xlsx')):

    df.append( pd.read_excel(filename))
```

Each data frame has a different row and column size. What I need is add a new column for each data frame call "TIME STAMP" and fill this column "TIME STAMP" with the same value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a column with `assign` but that requires a non-spaced name

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(dirname + '/*.xlsx'):
    df.append(pd.read_excel(filename).assign(TIMESTAMP='2020-01-01') )
```

Or you can manually create the new column:

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(dirname + '/*.xlsx'):
    d = pd.read_excel(filename)
    d['TIME STAMP'] = '2020-01-01'
    df.append(d)
```

Comment: The value of the column 'time stamp' is a list that I obtained from the name of each file xlsx. I mean this is my code:  date = [ ] df.append(pd.read_excel(filename).assign(TIMESTAMP= date)  and this is the issue that I have "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
"

Comment: The error says that the `date` has different length than one of your dataframes created from `xlsx` file. Is `date = [ ]` actually in your code or is it `df = [ ]`?

Comment: Yes, date is on my code: `df = [ ] date = [ ]   for filename in sorted(glob.glob(dirname + '/*.xlsx')):
    
    strAux = os.path.basename(filename)
    str = (os.path.splitext(strAux)[0])
    str = str.split("_")
    fechaAux = str[2]
    date.append(fechaAux)
    print(date)
    
    df.append(pd.read_excel(filename).assign(TIMESTAMP=date) )`

Comment: That's the problem, your `fecha` list is just an empty list (len==0), while your dataframes are not. `pandas` does not allow this to happen. Maybe you want `TIMESTAMP=np.nan` or `TIMESTAMP=''`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. But before assign `date` or `fecha`  I make this `date.append(fechaAux)`so `date` is not empty anymore

Answer (score 0):

`for filename in sorted(glob.glob(dirname + '/*.xlsx')):

```
strAux = os.path.basename(filename)
str = (os.path.splitext(strAux)[0])
str = str.split("_")
fechaAux = str[2]

print(fechaAux)

df.append(pd.read_excel(filename).assign(TIMESTAMP=fechaAux) )`
```